# How to share a Dropbox folder but hide collaborator/user’s emails?

Tags: email, sharing, dropbox, collaboration

I work with two different customers and need to share the same folder with each of them, but I don't want them to know of each other.

At the moment, any user who joins a shared Dropbox folder can see other users’ email. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

Cust A shares folder with You. You share Folder with Cust B. (Folder stays same, no copy.)
No Auto-sync will be there, but maybe they both will see each other.

The foolproof plan can be:

Cust A shares with You (Copy A). You Make Copy B and share it with Cust B. (Now you have two copies of folder.)
Possibly no auto-sync, but for sure Cust A & B cannot see each other. You could use something like Microsoft Auto-Sync Toy (with Echo action) to sync.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply send each of your customers/consultants a link to the folder (*share link* icon).

This allows them access to the folder and cannot have access to anymore information on the folder.

Comment: I need to collaborate with them though. Thanks anyway!